# THREEjs create an intersection plane for a raycast with negative origin

Tags: three.js

I have a THREEJS scene with an object that 'looks at my mouse'. This works fine and I am using a raycast to get the mouse position like so:

```
this.intersectionPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 10);
this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
this.pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
```

On the `mouse-move` event I `lookAt` the `pointOfIntersection` vector and the object rotates. This works really well.

```
onDocumentMouseMove = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
        this.raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(this.intersectionPlane, this.pointOfIntersection);
        let v3 = new THREE.Vector3(this.pointOfIntersection.x*0.05, this.pointOfIntersection.y*0.05, this.pointOfIntersection.z);
        if(this.pebbleLogo){
            this.pebbleLogo.lookAt(v3);
            // console.log(v3);
        }
        if(this.videoWall){
            this.videoWall.lookAt(v3);
        }
    }
```

BUT, I want to do the same thing with another object that lives at a z-depth of `-20` and the camera flies through to this position. At this point, it also flies through the `intersectionPlane` and the raycast no longer works.

The `intersectionPlane` is not added to the scene so it doesn't have a position that I can move so how do I make sure that it stays with the camera?

I can see that the `plane` has two properties:

```
normal - (optional) a unit length Vector3 defining the normal of the plane. Default is (1, 0, 0).
constant - (optional) the signed distance from the origin to the plane. Default is 0.
```

I have been able to move the `Plane` using a `translate` but this is not ideal as I need the plane to be in a constant position in relation to the camera (just in front of it). I tried to make the plane a child of the camera but it didn't seem to make any difference to its position.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform `renderer.render(scene, cam)`, the engine updates the transformation matrices of all objects that need to be rendered. However, since your camera and plane are not descendants of the scene, you'll have to manually update these matrices. The plane doesn't know that it's parent `camera` has moved, so you might need to perform `plane.updateMatrix()`. You can read about [manually updating transformation matrices in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.updateMatrix).

I think since only the parent moves, you might need to use `updateMatrixWorld()` or `updateWorldMatrix()` instead. But one of these 3 options should work.

**Edit**

Upon re-reading your code, it looks like you're using a purely [Mathematical `THREE.Plane` object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane). This is not an Object3D, which means it cannot be added as a child of anything, so it doesn't behave as a regular object.

My answer assumed you were using a [Mesh with PlaneGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=planege#api/en/geometries/PlaneGeometry), which **is** an Object3D, and it **can** be added as a child of the camera.

Comment: That’s if I add the Plane as a parent of the camera? Or is that irrelevant? The origin is always relative to the camera ?

Comment: @LeeProbert My mistake, I just realized you're using `THREE.PLane()`, which is not an Object3D and thus cannot be added as a child of `camera`. I added an edit to my answer to clarify.

Comment: I could still do the Raycast intersection with a Mesh Plane? Just use that instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly how [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter) calculates the position on the ground.

Comment: I added a mesh plane as a child of the camera and then used the updateMatrix in my render call. Thanks for the advice.